# Capistrano deploy fails with rake run (rails3 + rvm)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, capistrano

**EDIT:**
The issue here was that I used RVM on my local machine and rbenv on the server. This is highly not recommended, if you're managing several ruby installation (or upgrading your ruby version but do not want to change the system's) use either RVM or rbenv on all environments!
**/EDIT**

So I'll start with a bit history:
I'm in the process of upgrading our rails2 website to rails3. Most of the things are working properly by now, except Capistrano's deploy script. 
The current setup I have is:

- RVM (1.14.1) installed locally
- ruby-1.9.3-p194 (set to the project's folder)
- Capistrano v2.12.0 (upgraded from 2.6.0, but it doesn't work on 2.6.0 as well) installed as an RVM gem
- rvm-capistrano (1.2.2), added to the Gemfile (after doing some reading online and on SO)
- rbenv (with ruby 1.9.3p194 used globally) installed on the server

(by now if you see anything that doesn't make sense, please let me know)

Nothing changed in the deploy script, yet when I try to deploy to my testing server (let's call it *beta*) I get this error:

```
* executing `deploy:restart'
* executing "cd /home/foo/bar/current && rake RAILS_ENV=beta queue:restart_workers"
        servers: ["208.0..."]
        [208.0...] executing command
    *** [err :: 208.0...] rake aborted!
    *** [err :: 208.0...] no such file to load -- bundler/setup
    *** [err :: 208.0...] /home/foo/bar/releases/20120630161947/Rakefile:5
    *** [err :: 208.0...] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
     ** [out :: 208.0...] (in /home/foo/bar/releases/20120630161947)
        command finished in 1183ms
    failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/foo/bar/current && rake RAILS_ENV=beta queue:restart_workers'" on 208.0...
```

The relevant part on deploy.rb looks like this:

```
  task :restart do
    run "cd /home/foo/bar/current && rake RAILS_ENV=#{CAP_ENV} queue:restart_workers"
    run "cd /home/foo/bar/current && rake RAILS_ENV=#{CAP_ENV} db:migrate"
    run "touch #{deploy_to}/current/tmp/restart.txt"
  end
```

Needless to say, `rake RAILS_ENV=beta queue:restart_workers'` works perfectly when run manually on the server. Also, the application gets deployed (the code was copied from git, it's just the last part of the deploy fails).

Lastly, the error didn't change since before I installed rvm-capistrano and added to the Gemfile, so I'm not even sure it's related to rvm, I'm just guessing from looking online.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you want to be using both rbenv and rvm - they're both ways of managing multiple ruby versions.

Comment: I do have multiple ruby versions. I'm upgrading from ruby 1.8.7 + rails 2.3.2, and I understood it's not recommended to change the native ruby OS installation (aka on /usr/bin/ruby).

Comment: Both rvm and rbenv are for managing ruby versions, and they both do it in slightly different ways. Using both at the same time seems to be asking for trouble to me. rvm-capistrano is probably setting things up to use whatever rvm thinks is the current ruby, rather than what rbenv thinks

Comment: The thing I don't understand is, it's configured to be global so why would it matter to capistrano? I guess I'll try in a bit using the same setup on both the server and my machine and see how it goes..

Comment: Well if capistrano is setup to use rvm, rvm could conceivably be changing the ruby to a different one than the one rbenv is configured to use.

Comment: @FrederickCheung You were right, the problem was using rvm locally and rbenv on the server. I ended up uninstalling rvm and using rbenv, only because I read it's less intrusive and lighter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to work correctly, rbenv must  override all the ruby and gem-related executables with the shims it provides.

Usually this is done with a startup script (this is why it works when you login to your server) but Capistrano logs in without shell and thus does not run those scripts.

You must add the following to your deploy.rb :

```
set :default_environment, {
  'PATH' => "$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
}
```

and do not use anything rvm related on your server, rbenv and rvm really do not like each other

PS : a little more explanation on this topic : http://henriksjokvist.net/archive/2012/2/deploying-with-rbenv-and-capistrano/